# ASP NET CORE Can't scaffold Identity using existing DbContext - how do I specify options when scaffolding?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Steps to recreate:

1) create new `asp net core` mvc project.

2) create a new model and scaffold an API controller with read/write

3) delete bootstrap.css

4) change the created DbContext to inherit from IdentityDbContext

5) try to scaffold an identity

6) get error

---

I've scaffolded a set of objects from a data object which has given me:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class AllTheOtherStuffDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AllTheOtherStuffDbContext() : base("name=AllTheOtherStuffDbContext")
        { }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<WebApplication1.Models.Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to scaffold an identity set for my db but using the same context, so I change `DbContext` to `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>` as per some different answers I've found, but when scaffolding and generating code, I get this message:

```
Cannot use an existing DbContext with the '--useDefaultUI' option.
```

I looked up [UseDefaultUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc.identity.identitygeneratorcommandlinemodel.usedefaultui?view=aspnetcore-2.2)...

and in a separate project I see by scaffolding an Identity I get this line added to my startup.cs:

`services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();`

I presume the problem now is because I got rid of Bootstrap in my current project (because I hate it) so I want to STOP the scaffolding from trying to add that `DefaultUI` line - how can I do this while using visual studio? Can I specify a command line instead of using the menu option to add scaffolding?

Comment: What do you mean with "5) try to scaffold an identity" ? That's not totally clear.

Comment: IIRC, the scaffold dialog blocks until you select at least 1 page to scaffold... If you don't want to customize the pages I think you don't have to do anything. Does it run (with Login, Register pages) now?

Comment: You can scaffold a set of identity classes to auto-generate user login/registration etc. - right click main project, add scaffolded item, select Identity

Comment: Hmm, well I selected `overwrite all` pages - even though I didn't have any existing in my project yet anyway! and it worked! I will try to recreate this again later and try those steps again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have used `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>`

```
public class AllTheOtherStuffDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
     ...
}
```

You will have to use this DbContext here: `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AllTheOtherStuffDbContext>();`

To stop the ui scaffolding use `services.AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>()`

P.S. I dislike the bootstrap template too.

Comment: Yup thanks, I did add that `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AllTheOtherStuffDbContext>();` and it's working fine now, although it seems my initial issue preventing any scaffolding at all was simply that I wasn't selecting any pages to overwrite on the Add Scaffold box!!

Answer (score -4):

Create the project with the default Identity and then Scaffold Identity. This should work fine.